# how to docker-ize a composite node js project

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a typescript based NodeJs composite project. What I mean by composite is that I have several local dependecies, which are combine to form a master project.

So my main projects package.json looks something like this:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "local1-dep1": "file:../local1-dep1",
    "local2-dep2": "file:/some/dir/local2-dep2",
}
```

Now how do I dockerize this kind of project.How do I resolve this local projects (I do not intend to push this local dependecies to docker, as they are any way pushed to github as private). I am not pushing node_modules to my docker image to make my image small.

Is there any standard pratcice of how do I dockerize this kind of projects ?

Comment: If your `node_modules` aren't in your Docker image, what _is_ in it; how are you able to run it, without checking out the application source code separately (and once you do that, why not just use Node)?  What's in your current Dockerfile?

Comment: @DavidMaze when I run them locally it creates a link to the directroy in the node_modules, on linux system.

Comment: That's not inside your image, though.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes. But I want them as part of my image, to make my composite project work.
I thin I will hae to use mounting or making a copy of them on the image itself!